# Lost autocompletion in Time&Date location dialog

Tags: 15.04, time

Seems like I've accidentally uninstalled some package in 15.04 but I lost autocomletion in Time&Date location dialog. It still works on "Time&Date" tab, but doesn't work on Clocks tab/Choose locations...

Any ideas on how to fix this? Or maybe how to add the city manually in that dialog?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a confirmed bug:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-control-center/+bug/1440157

The launchpad link contains a temporary fix. It has been fixed but is waiting to make it's way to the stable repos.

Answer (score 0):

My own manual workaround:

1. Look for necessary timezones:

   `find /usr/share/zoneinfo/ -iname 'kiev*'`
2. Set them:

   `gsettings set com.canonical.indicator.datetime locations "['Asia/Yekaterinburg Yekaterinburg', 'America/Montreal Montreal', 'Europe/Kiev Kiev', 'Europe/Minsk Minsk']"`